# Javascript Countdown Timer Not Working in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I have a countdown timer that is working as expected when viewing in Chrome or Firefox. However, when viewing in Safari it has an error.

Here's the code:

```
    !function(e) {
    e.fn.countdown = function(t, n) {
        function s() {
            if (eventDate = Date.parse(o.date) / 1e3, currentDate = Math.floor(e.now() / 1e3), currentDate >= eventDate) {
                if ("undefined" === n || null == n)
                    return !1;
                n.call(this), clearInterval(interval)
            }
            seconds = eventDate - currentDate, 
                days = Math.floor(seconds / 86400), 
                seconds -= 60 * days * 60 * 24, 
                hours = Math.floor(seconds / 3600), 
                seconds -= 60 * hours * 60, 
                minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60), 
                seconds -= 60 * minutes, 
                a.find(".timeRefDays").text(1 == days ? "day" : "days"), 
                a.find(".timeRefHours").text(1 == hours ? "hour" : "hours"), 
                a.find(".timeRefMinutes").text(1 == minutes ? "minute" : "minutes"), 
                a.find(".timeRefSeconds").text(1 == seconds ? "second" : "seconds"), 
                "on" == o.format && (days = String(days).length >= 2 ? days : "0" + days, hours = String(hours).length >= 2 ? hours : "0" + hours, minutes = String(minutes).length >= 2 ? minutes : "0" + minutes, seconds = String(seconds).length >= 2 ? seconds : "0" + seconds),
                isNaN(eventDate) ? (alert("Invalid date. Here's an example: 12 Tuesday 2015 17:30:00"), clearInterval(interval)) : (a.find("> li .days").text(days), a.find("> li .hours").text(hours), a.find("> li .minutes").text(minutes), a.find("> li .seconds").text(seconds))
        }
        var a = jQuery(this), o = {
            date: null,
            format: null
        };
        t && e.extend(o, t), s(), interval = setInterval(s, 1e3)
    }
```

The error message in the Safari console is:
"Can't find variable: interval"

Why isn't this working in Safari?

Comment: You're calling `s()` before you assign `interval = setInterval(s, 1e3)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
    function initCountDown()
     {  
       if ('countdown' in $.fn) { 
       $('.time-left .time').each(function() { 
       var timer = this; 
       if ($(timer).data('countdownInstance') == undefined) { 
       $(timer).countdown($(timer).data('time'), 
       function(event) { 
           $(timer).find('.days .count').text(event.offset.totalDays);
           $(timer).find('.hours .count').text(event.offset.hours);
           $(timer).find('.minutes .count').text(event.offset.minutes); 
           $(timer).find('.seconds .count').text(event.offset.seconds);
                      });
               }             
          });         
    }        
}
```

This is my code. It is fine for FireFox and Chorme but not working in Safari.

Answer (score 0):

Add a declaration of the `interval` variable to the beginning of the function.

```
!function(e) {
e.fn.countdown = function(t, n) {
    var interval;
    function s() {
        if (eventDate = Date.parse(o.date) / 1e3, currentDate = Math.floor(e.now() / 1e3), currentDate >= eventDate) {
            if ("undefined" === n || null == n)
                return !1;
            n.call(this), clearInterval(interval)
        }
        seconds = eventDate - currentDate, days = Math.floor(seconds / 86400), seconds -= 60 * days * 60 * 24, hours = Math.floor(seconds / 3600), seconds -= 60 * hours * 60, minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60), seconds -= 60 * minutes, a.find(".timeRefDays").text(1 == days ? "day" : "days"), a.find(".timeRefHours").text(1 == hours ? "hour" : "hours"), a.find(".timeRefMinutes").text(1 == minutes ? "minute" : "minutes"), a.find(".timeRefSeconds").text(1 == seconds ? "second" : "seconds"), "on" == o.format && (days = String(days).length >= 2 ? days : "0" + days, hours = String(hours).length >= 2 ? hours : "0" + hours, minutes = String(minutes).length >= 2 ? minutes : "0" + minutes, seconds = String(seconds).length >= 2 ? seconds : "0" + seconds), isNaN(eventDate) ? (alert("Invalid date. Here's an example: 12 Tuesday 2015 17:30:00"), clearInterval(interval)) : (a.find("> li .days").text(days), a.find("> li .hours").text(hours), a.find("> li .minutes").text(minutes), a.find("> li .seconds").text(seconds))
    }
    var a = jQuery(this), o = {
        date: null,
        format: null
    };
    t && e.extend(o, t), s(), interval = setInterval(s, 1e3)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that took care of the console error, but I'm still getting the alert message saying it's not a valid date. It's also popping up multiple times now instead of just one.

Comment: What's the value of `o.date`? Different browsers support different date formats when parsing, and it may not be in a format that Safari understands.